# Textarea with maximum one row

Tags: html

Is it possible to have a textarea in HTML with a single line that never wraps to a 2nd line?
I'd like to behave pretty much like an input.

I've tried :

```
<textarea class="compact" rows="1" wrap="soft"> </textarea>

.compact{
    resize: none;
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

---

---

Why am I not using an `input` actually?
Mostly because of the IE 10 compatibility and requirement to copy-paste text in the control. If the pasted text contains `\r\n`, IE 10 will simply trim any other characters after `\r\n` and paste that result in the `input`.

For example, the text

```
1

2

3
```

will be pasted as `1` without the rest of the text.

Comment: *I'd like to behave pretty much like an input.*, what prevents you from using an Input?  Why would you want to use something that wasn't designed to be used the way you want?

Comment: You may be SOL without javascript... FWIW, I don't see why a text input wont work--copy/paste works fine. In your example, the input would have 1 2 3 showing without any breaks, even after copied back out...

Comment: It sounds like it does *exactly* what you want.  It sounds like you're asking for a control that will trim everything after `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it.  I wired up an jQuery listener.
Using this, no word wrapping is allowed, even when pasting a multi-line string into it.  And spaces are still preserved.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#formatTextArea').on("keyup", function () {
        var string1 = $('#formatTextArea').val()
        string1 = string1.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
        $('#formatTextArea').val(string1)
    });
});

<textarea class="compact" id="formatTextArea" rows="1" cols="30" wrap="off"></textarea>
```

Comment: I thought there might be a way without using JS. This looks good. Except one thing, this will capture all key ups even unintended ones like for example trying to select all text with Ctrl+A

Comment: True.  If you try this in your own project, though, it works perfectly.  You can arrow around, Ctrl+arrow, Ctrl+A, etc and notice no slow downs or weirdness.  I think since it's a listener, it can look at all keyups.

Comment: Just a small modification and it seems just fine. I've changed the event from keyup to input and it won't capture key shortcuts or commands anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can use [`wrap="soft"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#attr-wrap) and possibly [`max-length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#attr-maxlength)

```html
<textarea rows="1" wrap="soft" maxlength="20" ></textarea>
```

Comment: That's great but somehow I'm trying to build up a control behaving just like an input (one line only). The multi-line must be somehow unavailable...

Comment: I've tried using input instead and also JS hacks with manipulating text from clipboard but I don't wanna go that path...

Comment: I guess I don't follow...hit enter while typing and all the line breaks copy out in IE just fine...I believe the OP doesn't want line breaks

Comment: @Ted, if you attempt a copy-paste of a text with newline chars inside an input (type=text), in Chrome, the browser will actually paste the text and ignore the newlines by transforming them into a space character. What I'd like to achieve is the exact same thing, but on IE 10 as well. Unfortunately it is not possible using input, and I've tried somehow to achieve this with textarea but with no success

Comment: ahhh...i get it now. You want new lines, like \r\n, replaced with a space \s?

Comment: yeah, that would be fine... but I am unsure how to achieve that... If it's possible at least

Comment: @VasileF I can't seem to reproduce your problem... IE10, Chrome, and Firefox seem to have similar behavior

Comment: @apaul34208 It can be reproduced on IE 11 as well. Here : http://jsfiddle.net/1fatgo6x/ - copy paste the whole text from JS into the input and see that 2 and 3 are ignored.

Comment: @VasileF my bad... I was copy/pasting from the input not to the input

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little javascript:

```
var textarea = $("#your_textarea");

textarea[0].onpaste = function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        var output = textarea.val().replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ' ') ;        
        textarea.val(output )
    }, 1);
}
```

See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/50mgdc9w/6/)

Comment: I don't understand why pressing enter will replace the character with ' '

Comment: oh, this javascript isn't doing anything for hitting enter. It is only handling the paste. What you describe is the IE browser behavior based on the CSS (`wite-space:nowrap`). Delete the js and rerun it--you'll see it behaves the same

Comment: Yeah but... on IE it won't wrap the text to a 2nd line. On Chrome it does... I don't really get it

Comment: That would require more js to handle key events--see the other answer hooking into the keyup event. Different browsers do different things--typically, there's the way IE works, and the way all the other browsers work. IE is always 'special'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contenteditable` attribute on a div. Its widely supported in old browsers http://caniuse.com/#search=contenteditable

I created a small fiddle here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/wr14yLh5/

Html

```
<div contenteditable></div>
```

Css

```
div{
    background: green;
    color: #fff;
}

div br{
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```
$("div").keypress(function(e){ return e.which != 13; });
```